# How to find location of minimum dimension of contour using opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, c++

[image]
suppose this is our input image and now we have to detect the point of minimum dimension, which I show as the red dot in an [image]output image

Comment: Is opencv an absolute requirement?

Comment: Yes, I am using opencv for this assignment,

Comment: Is thier is any method for doing this ??

Comment: @AkshayKumawat, You should look at https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html (Distance Transform).